# How do virtual & special folders work?

Tags: windows, operating-system, filesystems, special-folders

Windows has several "virtual folders" and "special folders" (Wikipedia's names for them) that change the way the file system works. For example, the `Desktop` folder acts like the root of the file system hierarchy in some circumstances, even though `C:/` is the drive, also called the partition, that the entire file system is on, and therefore logically `Desktop` should be under `C:/`. Screenshots:[image: Picture of Desktop folder, with <code>This PC</code> circled][image: Picture of <code>This PC</code>, showing that <code>C:/</code> isn't always the root of the filesystem] There are also the `Library` folders. Also, with `msysGit` and `Cygwin` on your computer, the program's folder then magically becomes the root of the file system.

I'm sure there are instances on other OS's, but I only really work with Windows, although it seems Linux is much less abstracted.

How do applications do this? Is it just a really complicated shell script, or something that only affects certain programs (Wikipedia says `Desktop` is only the root folder in `Windows Explorer`, for example)? Is it similar to how on Linux all folders are "mounted", even the root folder? Even if the OS developers don't usually give away their secrets, I would still like to know the basic method, if possible.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate on what he/she didn't like about my question? Maybe I could fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [wikipedia's entry for special folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) says that:

> The Desktop virtual folder is the root of the Windows Shell namespace,
>   which contains other virtual folders.

This is not the same as saying it's "the root of the file system hierarchy". Windows has a set of set of virtual folders. All of these are nested under Desktop.

For Win7 and up, the default filesystem layout is actually:

- Desktop -> C:\Users\(username)\Desktop
- My Documents -> C:\Users\(username)\Documents
- Downloads -> C:\Users\(username)\Downloads

These aliases mean something to the explorer shell, but not at the filesystem level (open cmd.exe and see what I mean).

At the filesystem level, and to an application, the filesystem path is what is going to matter. It takes extra API calls (the use of [SHGetSpecialFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to figure out where on the filesystem that special folder lives; the app only cares about where in the filesystem it needs to target.

As for Cygwin, I strongly suspect that it's doing something totally different. Unix has a special call, `chroot()`, that really does modify the root for the currently running shell. This means that applications running under that shell have absolutely no knowledge of the directory structure below the `chroot()'d` path, and this is generally done for security reasons. In fact, this is usually referred to as a [chroot jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot), because it isn't an alias or a virtual directory, and can't be escaped from (unless there's a bug in the kernel).

Comment: For all intents & purposes, Desktop (the virtual folder, not physical) acts as the root of the filesystem hierarchy, at least to some programs like Windows Explorer. That's what I was trying to say. I noticed the Desktop folder inside C:\Users\<username>, and always wondered if that were the same folder as the virtual Desktop.

Comment: if Cygwin uses a chroot jail, how do you access the whole file? Also, this doesn't explain how the explorer shell puts `C:/` under `Desktop`. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to take out one of your "username"s. I hope you don't mind, but I suggested the edit for you. I'm not sure how it works, but I think if you say OK it stays. Either way I'm fine with it; at least I brought it to your attention. **Edit**: Nevermind, I see you already accepted it.

Comment: @trysis Thanks for catching that. It was near the end of the day and I was ready to head out.

Comment: @trysis re: C:\ and Desktop -- and the answer is, it can't; `Desktop` is actually a subdirectory down below C:\. The trees to the right of my explorer pane show (1) Favorites, (2) Libraries, (3) Computer, and (4) Network. Could you post a pic where you're seeing C:\ nested under `Desktop`?

Comment: No problem. As to `C:/` being under `Desktop`, well, technically it's 2 folders under. From `Windows 8` & back I forget how far, the hierarchy goes `Desktop->My Computer->C:`. On `8.1`, replace `My Computer` with `This PC` (supposedly because it reflects how computers are now a commodity because of the Internet, but I personally don't like it). I'll post a screenshot, give me a second.

Comment: Posted pictures. Sorry, they're huge, I'll try to shrink them while still letting them be legible.

Comment: @trysis Ha - no, they're great. Ok, so "This PC", aka "My Computer" isn't even a virtual directory. I'm not sure what to call it, other than a top-level container that isn't anything other than a list of drives on your system (C:, D:, etc), favorites, etc. Just to give you an idea of just how much of a placeholder this is, take a look at [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/q/655804/105558) that discusses how to remove folders from being listed in it. Applications will never care about "This PC".. it's purely for users to have a nice starting place.

Comment: Wow, so you can delete folders by modifying the `registry`? O.O... I have seen references to folders being `XML` files, maybe `My Computer`/`This PC` is one of these. Still leaves open the question of how in the heck THAT can happen, but that's another story, that will be told another time.